# How to involve non Muslim users from other SE sites here

Tags: discussion, users, stackexchange

Inspired by [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9482/should-more-non-muslims-read-this-site) This site is proving to be a valuable resource for non Muslims. It's been more than a year that this site is active and I strongly feel that the non Muslim users from other SE sites are our Ideal demographic to attract. It would be nice to see participation of users from other SE sites on Islam.SE. The current trend on Islam.SE makes me think that there are fewer interested Muslims to contribute content of the level which you may find by high quality Islamic scholars which would involve a lot of technical concepts. In the interest of a pragmatic approach we should stop pursuing this unnecessarily high bar and concentrate on simple questions and answers useful to a non Muslim demographic which is typically found on SE sites.

For this to happen we need ways to encourage users from other SE sites to ask questions and answer questions in Islamic perspective. This will serve a two fold benefit: that it will help in getting high quality questions from seasoned users of other SE sites and answering with an Islamic perspective would help them understand more about Islam and that would cause the motivated users to read more about Islam. Contrary to some other  opinions we already have one user from a J.SE who is contributing quality content on this site. This is an interesting development but we should brainstorm ways to bring in more users from other SE sites to contribute here.
Those who don't see this a way to move ahead can skip answering this question (as was discussed in chat) , for those who can offer some interesting or out of the box ideas to improve participation of users from other sites can please answer this question

Comment: see also: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/94/22

Comment: The Stack Exchange model is designed around the idea of congregating *expertise*.  Exactly what sort of expertise do you hope to garner by explicitly targetting *non-experts* as the ideal demographic?

Comment: expertise is not about knowledge its a trait which is domain independent , anybody can become expert, SE users of other sites have a better chance to become Islamic experts then other first timers. Expertise here has largely to do with following the SE model and  experienced users from one site have a better chance to be come expert on another site. And we already have successful examples in all religion sites.

Answer (score 2):

What is this "unreasonably high bar" you speak of?  This site has been around for over a year, and there's been barely any movement to limit the scope of acceptable topics *at all*.  Pretty much anything that pertains to "Islam" is considered on-topic here, regardless of level of expertise.

We don't need to lower the bar: We need to *define* it.

Going out and attracting a community, whether one of experts or non-experts, only really works if you can define what that community *is*.  We're not looking for people to *become* our community, what we're doing is defining the community so that people *who are already part of that community* outside of the site now have a place to congregate, or people who are interested in becoming part of that community know where to go.

Your proposal does nothing to define the (new) community you're seeking to build, just the sorts of questions and answers you want them to bring to the table; questions and answers which can be brought by…well…anyone, really.  Until you can define a community, both by the expertise they can provide and the commonality that distinguishes them from other communities, I don't see this idea succeeding at all.